# LED strip does not have SMD Resistors

Tags: power-supply, led, resistors, led-strip

I just bought a cheap 3.5 x 2.8 mm  12 V waterproof white light LED strip. By waterproof I mean that it is covered with silicone all over. The suspicious part is that I cannot see a single SMD resistor in the whole led strip. The style is basic, the strip has cutouts after every three LEDs.

So for driving it with a 12 V 20 Amps power supply, do I need to add a current limiting resistor myself or is there some in-built resistance of the traces used or something that I don't know of?[image: Small part of the Led Strip]

P.S The small black markings are indeed markings and not SMD resistors soldered onto them.

Comment: The LED strip length is 5 metres.

Comment: Have you got a link to where you ordered the strip, or at least a photo?

Comment: https://megaeshop.pk/5m-300-led-strip-light-3528-5050-5630-smd-ribbon-tape-roll-waterproof-dc-12v.html

Comment: The pictures are misleading though.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the picture

Comment: @Herman what is the model # of the stip or LED's on the strip?

Comment: 300 leds on the 5 metre strip. Model is 3528.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like they have [thick-film printed](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1434&context=masters_theses) resistive material (ink) rather than installing SMT resistors. That's what those black rectangles are. A way to make it a bit cheaper and crappier. One resistor for 3 LEDs is correct for 12V. It's probably the same FPC layout as for resistors.

If you measure the resistance from end-to-end of one of the rectangles (vertically in your photo) you should be able to measure them. Probably somewhere in the 100\$\Omega\$ range.

Comment: Holy crap they figured out how to save $0.001 yet again. Which means the LEDs are gonna be low efficiency low CRI garbage. Which means the savings will probably be offset by extra electricity cost compared to a well built more expensive decent efficiency strip. Now I wonder what kind of counterfeit 3M adhesive is on the back...

Comment: @bobflux The stuff they ship to South Asia is negotiated to be significantly cheaper than that sent to picky European customers, and they cleverly find a way make it for that price. That's a 5m LED strip with 300 LEDs retailing for $2.34 USD (0.78 cents per LED including FPC, resistors (of a sort), reel and silicone sealant!

Comment: Well, I suppose that with the large surface area—compared to an SMT device—the resistors will run a bit cooler.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  SMT resistors are sealed in glass passivation and probably typically accurate to +/-1% (5% stated tolerance, but they're made much better). Those ones maybe 10% or 20%. And printing on bare copper (probably what they did) might not last with expansion and contraction. The (likely) B-grade LEDs they used will vary quite a bit too so 20% isn't all that big a deal for visual brightness. So.. probably just good enough for the target market.

Comment: My parents asked me to install it in the house and i was a bit skeptical as i never heard of a led strip having no resistors. I bought it because even i was surprised at first.Typically the 5m led strips start from 3.3 usd in my country with no waterproofing and non RGB. RGB version starts from 5.4 usd,

Comment: Anyways i was foolish enough to try to turn it on from my psu and nothing happened, they didnt fuse or anything (if there was a high current passing through them, they wouldve blown up/fused) with this one so i assume that your answer is the most logical explanation.

Comment: I measured its resistance and it was variable from a 400 ohms to 10 kilo ohms. I did notice that there were two small copper pads and the resistive ink was being used to connect these two pads.